# Can I have indexing of nodes and relations (normal and fulltext) using http in transactions in neo4j?

Tags: python, transactions, indexing, neo4j, cypher

I am new to `Neo4j` and have a question:

All I want is to be able to `add`/`update` nodes and relationships, have their props immediately `indexed`, some with `fulltext indexing`, and everything enclosed in `transactions`, usable from `Python`. Is this possible?

I have the following `requirements` for using Neo4j:

1. Use it from `Python`.
2. Immediate indexing of `nodes` and their properties.
3. Immediate indexing of `relationships` and their properties.
4. `Fulltext indexing` of some node/relationships properties.
5. Adding and population of `new indexes` for an existing graph.
6. Several separate read and write calls `enclosed in one transaction` (with a separate commit or rollback command at the end).

*Added 2013-07-02: I'd like to integrate Neo4j with the plone cms, which has multiple transactional databases connected. A user can make a call to the cms, which will in return `affect multiple databases`. So just because Neo4j hasn't returned an error doesn't mean the transaction should commit - an abort can be caused by an error somewhere else, in another database or piece of code*.

From the experiments I have done so far (using `neo4j-community-2.0.0-M03`) it seems to me:

- configuring `[node|relationship]_auto_index` will give me 2,3,4, but not 5. And
  there is only one auto_index for nodes/relationships, so either all of the 
  attributes are fulltext, or none.
- The `label/schema` indexes would give me a run-time configurable indexes for 2, but not for 3, as they only work for nodes.
- The `REST API` gives me 1,2,3,4, would allow 5 (because I could add existing
  nodes/relationships  and their properties to new indexes). It can't do 6, because
  outside of batches its not transactional. So errors that happen after running the batch
  could not trigger an abort.
- The `transactional endpoint` in combination with `auto_indexing` and `labels/schema` 
  gives me 1,2,4,5 (nodes only) and 6, but not 3, because labels/schema only works on
  nodes. And `Cypher` doesn't allow adding e.g. relationships to indexes.

My big hope is that I missed something, and all 6 requirements could be fulfilled. Any hints?

Comment: 5. with auto_indexing, you have to 'touch' properties on existing nodes in order to be indexed, so it can be done (just traverse the graph and do my_node.my_prop_value = my_node.my_prop_value)
 6. if you use Gremlin over REST, you can manage the transactions as you want (in a single call). It may be possible to do it with Cypher also, but I'm not very familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on 'touching'. I see how I could first modify the list of auto_index attributes, then touch all nodes. Regarding the transactions - I'd like to mix multiple neo4j calls (read,write) with python logic, and only want to commit at the very end, if no error has occoured on the python side. So commiting one single script wouldn't be enough.

Comment: There's a [transactional REST interface](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-transactional.html) in the making, which would help you with 6. It's still experimental though.

Comment: My last point mentions that transaction rest interface - it gives me all but 3. Maybe I need to live with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to go with the (currently experimental) transactional REST endpoint. In combination with labels and declarative indexing this solves requirements 1, 2, 5, 6.

Combining this with auto indexing for relationship properties solves 3 and 4. Rebuilding an relationship auto index can be done with cypher:

```
start r = rels(*) set r.<prop> = r.<prop>
```

for all autoindexable properties. For larger datasets consider using `limit` and `skip` in order to have control over transaction size while indexing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using your advice I created a sample setup using dbpedia data: https://baach.de/Members/jhb/dbpedia-and-neo4j-first-steps-ii#section-2